# Android Gps Disable Updates

Tags: android, gps

How do I disable location updates in onLocationChanged() after clicking on stop button also it is continuously updating the location.
I have used the code mentioned here.
Please help me out how to solve this.

```
public class AndroidGPSSampleActivity extends Activity {

private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 30000; // in Milliseconds
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected Button retrieveLocationButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
        MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
        MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
        new MyLocationListener()
    );
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new MyLocationListener());

    retrieveLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCurrentLocation();
        }
    });
}

protected void showCurrentLocation() {

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        String message = String.format(
                "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
        );

        Toast.makeText(AndroidGPSSampleActivity.this, "Sample test",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(AndroidGPSSampleActivity.this, message,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String message = String.format(
            "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
            location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
        );
        Toast.makeText(AndroidGPSSampleActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
        Toast.makeText(AndroidGPSSampleActivity.this, "Provider status changed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(AndroidGPSSampleActivity.this,"Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        System.out.println("==onProviderEnabled=" + s);
        Toast.makeText(AndroidGPSSampleActivity.this, "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation about LocationManager ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest you to make `MyLocationListener` as class field and later you can access it from any inner class. You can disable updates for a specific listener by calling [removeUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.location.LocationListener%29) method of `LocationManager` class.

```
public class AndroidGPSSampleActivity extends Activity {

    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1;
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 30000;
    private MyLocationListener listener = new MyLocationListener();
    ...
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
```

Updates can be stopped in any place of code by using the following:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }
});
```